# Unexpected termination when pushing a shared_ptr into a list

Tags: c++, stl

I have some function:

```
void addNormalLine(int id, LineNumber number, Rate smsRate, Rate callRate) {
list<Account>::iterator iAccounts;
        findAccount(iAccounts, id);
        if(iAccounts == listOfAccounts.end()){
            throw "AccountDoesNotExist";
        }
if(lineExists(number)){
            throw "LineExists";
        } else{
            iAccounts->increaseNumLines();
            shared_ptr<Line> currentLine(new Line(id, number, smsRate, callRate));  //here I have some problems
            listOfLines.push_back(currentLine);  //without these two rows it works, but didn't add lines to my list
        }
    }
Account, Rate, LineNumber - some classes
```

but It always add only one or two numbers, if I add 3 it always terminates and and I recieve `terminated, exit value: 3`, I tried google it, but didn't find, what is than supposed to mean, thanks in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with eclipse, and there's not enough information here to answer your question. We need to see more of your code. The first thing you should do is run this through the debugger to see where the program is terminating, so that you can tell where the error is and avoid dumping hundreds of lines of code into this question (because no one will read them).

Comment: @Tyler McHenry: You know here is a problem, I can't do it, I don't know why, but my eclispe terminates before I reach these rows

Comment: exit value comes out of main() normally.  whats the exception handling etc.  whats the definition for listOfLines

Comment: I have one major class named company, so there I have in private section listOfLines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad practice to use strings as exception values. Use classes for exceptions, at least something like std::runtime_error() or better create a new class derived from it.

Make sure you catch exceptions you're throwing in this method.

What's the definition of `findAccount`?

Comment: I had 6 statements addLine, I tried every two, it works perfectly, but with third it fails